# C# UWP Change global app background

Tags: c#, colors, background, uwp, resize

I need to change default white background that is showing on the right side when I am resizing the window of UWP application, and I need to do it dynamically.

I have tried:

```
var newBackground = Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
if (newBackground != null)
{
    newBackground.Color = newColor;
}
```

The newBackground is changed, but not affecting the application.

Any help?

Comment: What is `background` in your code?

Comment: It is mistake, I have updated my question.

Comment: Do you want to override `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush`?

Comment: I want to change default background color of App. If you set Light theme that color is White, and if you set Dark theme that color is Black. I is behind the main root of App.

Comment: But `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` has the same behaviour as you want. Check [here](http://metro.excastle.com/xaml-system-brushes)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush`

```
Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"] = Colors.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your issue we need to check something in background:

When you check the ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush in the generaic.xaml(To konw what is generaic.xaml you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources)), you will find that ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush is defined three times in "Default","HighContrast" and also "Light". So that when you call request theme all colors will be changed in different themes.

```
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark
```

So go back to your question, if you change the request theme to "Dark" you will find that the change color code:

```
    newBackground.Color = newColor;
```

will not change since there is a default setting for "Dark".(It works for default/Light theme)
And it seems we cannot modify this theme brush at runtime from code behind.

I think the only way for this is to **create theme color** yourself then change the color by **set the element explictly**.

To set the theme color. New [acrylic document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/acrylic) provide a good point for us. Here I  write a simple sample for you to show how default theme works:

1. Create a dictionary and insert the following code:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Blue"></SolidColorBrush>
       </ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow"></SolidColorBrush>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
   ```
2. Add it to app.xaml:

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```

To explictly set the element, do something like mygrid.background=xxxx. If you want to trigger it when resize, change the propery in adaptivetrigger.